# How to use value from any element in my node js program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
Element (<input id="pagenum-input" class="form-control" aria-label="..." value="1" min="1" max="28">)
```

I want to use the Value of max(28) as value of variable maximum that i have created in 2nd loop. How i can get the value of max from input tag to my program? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getPic() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  for (let j=2; j<=6; j++) {
    await page.setViewport({width: 2000, height: 2500})
    await page.goto('http://epaper.freepressjournal.in/');
    await page.click('body > div > div.common_section > div > div > div.rw_rightcrousel > div > div:nth-child('+j+') > a > div > img');  
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.click('#left-chunk-1 > img');
    var maximum; 
    for (let i= 1; i<=maximum; i++) {
      await page.waitFor(2000);
      await page.screenshot({path: '//192.168.2.19/em/automatic downloading/Puppeteer/freepressjournal/'+j+''+i+'.png'});
      await page.waitFor(2000);    
      await page.click('#page-div > a.right_arrow_pgright.btn_next');      
    }
  }

  await browser.close();
}

getPic();

// This loop will automatically get the value of max that is 28.
// The value of max will vary according to pages. The program should accept
// the value of max in maximum and run the loop accordingly.
for (let i= 1; i<=maximum; i++)
```

Comment: Hello Hammand, Welcome to stackoverflow. If you check your code you have defined variable called `maximum`, but you have not assigned any value to it. Kindly let us know what value you need to assign to `maximum`. you mentioned *The value of max will vary according to pages* but this is not sufficient

Comment: Where is the element containing `max="28"`? Is it on some other page? Your own?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar  Thank you for you help.
But it is not i want to assign value of variable. There is a page "http://epaper.freepressjournal.in/2176664/Free-Press-Mumbai-Edition/30-May-2019#page/1/1" In this page you will find an element <input id="pagenum-input" class="form-control" aria-label="..." value="1" min="1" max="28">. Now in this page the value of max is 28. I want to assign this value of max to my variable maximum.

Comment: @ChrisG You can find this element on "http://epaper.freepressjournal.in/2176664/Free-Press-Mumbai-Edition/30-May-2019#page/1/1" on this page.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interact with any element on the page with the help of `page.evaluate` function. Here's how you can find the input element of interest and access one of its attributes:

```
var maximum = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.getElementById("pagenum-input").getAttribute("max");
});
```

Comment: I am getting Error: (node:2012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null while using this code.

Comment: It means that the element is not on the page, but when it **does** exist this is the way to get `max` from it.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't used the code in the following loop. Now it is working fine. Thanks alot .!!